# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: RegDwight]
[image: splattne]
[image: Tim N]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Tim N has asked to step down and pass his diamond onto someone with more spare time to devote to the site. I'd like to thank Tim for all the time and effort he put into German.SE as a moderator and I hope he continues to enjoy this site as a regular user.

In the meantime, Takkat has graciously stepped up to volunteer his time and help moderate:

[image: Takkat]

Please be patient with him as he comes up to speed. Welcome, Takkat!

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is a fine decision to choose Takkat for the job. He is available nearly round the clock and I've never seen a stupid posting by him.

Gratulation Takkat. Jetzt beginnt der Ernst des Lebens! ;)

Comment: Thank you :) and let's thank @TimN too for the wonderful job he has done.