# Hilfe, ich spreche kein Englisch! (work in progress)

Tags: support, german-help

**Deutsch:** Hier entsteht die deutschsprachige Willkommensseite und Hilfe für unsere Seite (siehe [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/839/2594)). Sobald wir sie für prinzipiell nützlich erachten, wird alles bis zur ersten Linie sowie der Hinweis im Titel entfernt und sie wird an exponierten Stellen verlinkt. Auf [dieser getrennten Seite](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594) finden sich Richtlinien und Diskussionen hierfür. Bitte besuche sie zuerst.

**English:** This is the building place for the German welcome page and help center (see [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/839/2594)). As soon as we consider it usable, everything until the first line as well as the note in the title will be removed and it will be linked at prominent places. There is [a separate page](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594) for guidelines on this page and discussions about it. Please visit it first.

---

Willkommen auf German Language SE, einer Frage-und-Antwort-Seite über die deutsche Sprache. Diese Hilfe erklärt die Nutzung dieser Seite auf Deutsch. Am besten fängst Du mit der [Tour](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/2594) an.

Übersicht:

- [Tour](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/2594)

- Fragen

  - Worüber kann ich hier fragen?
  - Was für Fragen sollte ich nicht stellen?
  - […]
- Antworten

  - Was heißt es, wenn eine Antwort akzeptiert wurde?
  - […]
- Erfahrung (Reputation) und Moderation
- Accounts
- […]

Wie Du siehst, ist diese Seite noch nicht vollständig. Wenn Du Bedarf an Erklärungen zu einem bestimmten Thema hast, kannst Du Deinen Wunsch [hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594) äußern oder in unserem [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language) fragen. Wenn Du Fragen über diese Hilfe hast, darüber diskutieren oder daran mitarbeiten möchtest, besuche bitte [diese Seite](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594).

---

<sup>**English:** This is the main page of the German help as proposed [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/839/2594). See [this question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594) if you have questions about this help, want to discuss it or contribute to it.</sup>

Comment: Sollte es nicht »Hilfeseite« statt »Hilfe« heißen? (»Diese Hilfeseite erklärt die Nutzung ...«) Hilfe ist etwas, das jemand leistet und ein anderer in Anspruch nimmt. Die Hilfe selbst tut aber gar nichts. Insbesondere kann eine Hilfe nichts erklären, sondern nur der, der die Hilfe leistet. Und die Hilfe wird im vorliegenden Fall von einer Internetseite geleistet, daher erklärt diese Seite etwas, und nicht die von ihr geleistete Hilfe.

Comment: Wie lautet eigentlich die Frage?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es gibt keine Frage im eigentlichen Sinne (muss es auch nicht geben, da wir auf Meta sind). Dies ist ein Rohbau, wo ein deutsches Abbild der [Tour](http://german.stackexchange.com/tour) und des [Help-Centers](http://german.stackexchange.com/help) entstehen soll. Zur Zeit ist hier wenig los, da es mir an Zeit und Nerven fehlt, die grafischen Teile der Tour zu übersetzen, aber es ist jeder eingeladen, hier mitzuwirken. Wenn Du bessere Vorschläge für Formulierungen hast, fühl Dich frei, sie zu ändern.

Comment: Ja aber was willst du mit diesem Posting bezwecken? Sollen wir das kommentieren? Sollen wir darin Fehler suche? Du machst ja auch keine Aufforderung. Mir ist der Zweck dieses Postings einfach nicht klar. Deinem letzen Kommentar entnehme ich, dass du damit um bessere Vorschläge für Formulierungen bittest. Das solltest du vielleicht bei der "Frage" irgendwo noch dazuschreiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Ja aber was willst du mit diesem Posting bezwecken?* – Dieser Post soll (wenn er fertig ist) als Hilfeseite an geeigneten Stellen verlinkt werden. — Sollen wir das kommentieren? Sollen wir darin Fehler suche? – Ja. Vor allem aber sind alle eingeladen es zu erweitern. Wenn Du z. B. [diese Seite](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) übersetzen möchtest, kannst Du eine neue Antwort anlegen und dies tun. Für Meta-Diskussionen u. Ä. hierüber gibt es eine [extra Frage](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/977/2594).

Answer (score 1):

## Tour

<sup>([Link zum englischen, interaktiven Original](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour))</sup>

Dies ist ein Platzhalter und Beispiel für die Struktur.

[image]