# Die Sprachvorgabe für Meta ist aufgehoben

Tags: discussion, language, meta

[Robert Cartaino](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino) schrieb gerade auf Meta Latin Language [Folgendes](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/should-all-latin-question-titles-be-permitted/70?noredirect=1#comment176_70) (Hervorhebung von mir):

> We used to say if you want us (the Community Team) to be familiar with your community issues, meta posts would have to be in English. But on the rare, rare occasion where this was ever an issue, a post is easily Google-translated. **Meta is for the community, so they should post in whichever lanage is most comfortable for *them.*** The reason to try and enforce *"you can post {spanish} everywhere... except meta",* in my opinion, was too obscure to worry about in actual practice, so I never worried about it.

Auf Deutsch: Meta existiert für die Nutzer; sie mögen daher in der Sprache schreiben, die für sie am angenehmsten ist. Damit ist die [bisherige Vorgabe](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/2594), dass Meta auf Englisch sein soll, aufgehoben.

---

## The language restriction for Meta is gone

[Robert Cartaino](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/robert-cartaino) just [wrote](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/should-all-latin-question-titles-be-permitted/70?noredirect=1#comment176_70) on Meta Latin Language (boldface mine):

> We used to say if you want us (the Community Team) to be familiar with your community issues, meta posts would have to be in English. But on the rare, rare occasion where this was ever an issue, a post is easily Google-translated. **Meta is for the community, so they should post in whichever lanage is most comfortable for *them.*** The reason to try and enforce *"you can post {spanish} everywhere... except meta",* in my opinion, was too obscure to worry about in actual practice, so I never worried about it.

This supersedes [the old rule](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/2594) that Meta posts should be English.

Comment: Also im Klartext: Deutsch und Englisch wie auf main?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Japp.

Comment: Ar deireadh!!!!

Comment: Naja, dadurch ändert sich ja jetzt eigentlich nicht wirklich viel. Man sollte weiterhin versuchen Fragen, welche die Abläufe auf der Seite erklären auch auf English verfügbar zu machen. Wenn ich das richtig beobachtet habe, dann haben wir ja auch viele nicht Muttersprachler hier, denen sollten zumindest das Wichtigste auch zugänglich sein.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Und Nichtmuttersprachler möchtest Du auf Englischsprecher einschränken? Es kommen gerade viele Flüchtlinge nach Deutschland, von denen viele kein Englisch können. Der gemeinsame Nenner auf einer Seite, die sich ums Deutsche dreht, sollte wohl Deutsch sein.

Comment: @user Nö, möchte ich nicht. Prinzipiell wäre es wünschenswert, wenn sämtliche Informationen in allen Sprachen zur Verfügung stehen würden. Leider ist die Lokalisierung für die Nutzeroberfläche (noch) nicht in deutsch verfügbar, demnach ist die vollständige Umstellung auf Deutsch per se nicht möglich. Ich wollte nur zum Ausdruck bringen, dass es offener und transparenter ist, zumindest die wichtigsten Sachen auch auf Englisch zugänglich zu machen, da es ja allgemein die Sprache der Benutzeroberfläche ist.

Answer (score 12):

Aus Erfahrung schlage ich folgende kleine Ausnahme vor: Bugs und Feature-Requests, die nicht von den Moderatoren umgesetzt werden können, sollten nach Möglichkeit auf Englisch verfasst werden, um die Bearbeitung zu erleichtern. Falls irgendjemand sich dazu nicht in der Lage fühlt, darf er aber gerne auf Deutsch posten – wir müssen dann halt übersetzen.

---

From experience I would suggest the following exception: Bugs and feature requests that cannot be realised by the moderators should be in English, if possible, to streamline realising them. However, if somebody does not feel able to adhere to this, that’s also okay – we’ll just have to translate it.

Answer (score 5):

Da die Regel von "oben" aufgehoben wurde, sollten wir, um sinnvoll Support leisten zu können, eine eigene Sprachregelung für unser Meta einführen. Ich finde, wir sollten die Sprachregelung von unserem Main übernehmen:

**Auf meta.german.SE darf auf Englisch und auf Deutsch gepostet werden.**

**On meta.german.SE, posting in English or German is possible.**

Möglicherweise ergänzt um die von Wrzl genannte Ausnahme.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the many users who may not yet have a deep knowledge in German we should keep German posts on Meta low.

Meta is important as it is where we create the shape of German Language, where we give guidelines on posting, and where our Help section finally evolves.

We should be open to include all  opinions including those of users who may not yet speak German fluently enough to fully understand a question or to participate.

Therefore I believe it is fine to allow German post as an exception but we should not make it the rule.

Comment: Wholly concur here, though as an English speaker/German learner and currently an "outsider" to this site I'm probably inappropriately biased. Personally, I just started learning German through Duolingo and thought that this site would eventually be a great supplemental resource. While it's reasonably expected to find a large portion of the main site in German, I was a bit overwhelmed and intimidated when I also found the Meta site to have a substantial amount of non-English (and non-translated) content.

Comment: It's also worth noting that automated translation sites don't always get it right, and passing a whole page (or large portions of one) through a translation app just for readability can obscure the meaning of a post that intentionally has mixed-language content to suit the needs of the current discussion.